# NodeJS App with PM2 and daily changed json file

Tags: node.js, pm2

I currently have a NodeJS app running in PM2. The app displays data from a JSON file. The data is retrieved daily at 12 o'clock via a CURL command via system cron. In order for the data to load in the frontend I always have to execute a "pm2 reload ...". Which is quite annoying to me.

Anybody have an idea how I can solve the problem in the most elegant way? I have not worked with PM2 yet so my stupid question :)

Best

Comment: can you show how you're loading the file after it has been updated? If its outside of a timer or middleware, i.e on server start then it needs reloading. Seeing your code would help. Now for *the most elegant way*, well that would be to parse the json on fetch and put it into a database, then not load the file at all but instead do a database query

Comment: Thanks you have already helped me with your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not really PM2 related. When the JSON file changes you have to re-read the file into memory by importing/requiring it again. Use fs.watch to watch for file changes or add a built-in timer to reread file after midnight.

Comment: I already do that with `fs.readFileSync()` I think it is a PM2 related problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for not answering. I have two possible solutions. I myself chose version 2 because there I do not need external cronjobs.

Option-1:

I call an API with CURL on host on midnight and write it to a JSON file. I read the file with fs.promises and watch with "chokidar" about file changes.

```js
const fs = require('fs').promises,
    path = require('path'),
    chokidar = require('chokidar'),
    filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../<PATH_TO_FILE/<FILE>.json');

watcher = chokidar.watch(filePath, { persistent: true });
watcher.on('change', () => {
    getJSONData();
});

const getJSONData = async () => {
    try {
        let getFileData = await fs.readFile(filePath, { encoding: 'utf-8' });
        return (erg = JSON.parse(getFileData));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error when call json file.');
    }
};
```

Option-2:

I call the API inside a function with the node_module "node-schedule".

```js
require('dotenv').config();

const { <API_SERVICE_MODULE> } = require('<API_SERVICE_MODULE>'),
    schedule = require('node-schedule'),
    API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY,
    LABEL = process.env.LABEL;

const API = new <API_SERVICE_MODULE>({
    projectId: API_KEY,
});

const getDataFromAPI = async () => {
    try {
        const data = await API.<METADATA>(LABEL);
        return data;
    } catch (err) {
        return 'Error with fetching data from API';
    }
};

schedule.scheduleJob('*/10 * * * *', () => {
    getDataFromAPI();
});
```

**FYI: Both ways working with PM2**